# Losing the git name branch information after a merge

Tags: git, merge

I'm reworking a github project of mine. My problem is: once branches have been merged I lost the name of the merged branch (I use gitk or git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph). Here how I proceeded:

1/ Firstly, because I used to work a lot in master branch committing unstable stuffs I preferred working with a recommended way with 2 branches: 1/ working in an unstable 'dev' git branch; 2/ an always-stable-and-ready-for-prod git branch named 'master'. So I renamed 'master' for 'dev' branch. I destroyed all previous works on master (I know it's bad but it's ok because I work alone):

```
git branch -m master dev 
git push origin :master
git push --set-upstream origin dev
```

2/ Now I want to merge 'version 0.1' with the 'prototype' branch and 'version 0.2' from the 'dev' branch.

```
git checkout -b master
git reset --hard <sha1-of-initial-commit>
git merge --no-ff origin/prototype       # version 0.1 # origin
git merge --no-ff <sha1-from-dev-branch> # version 0.2 # local
git push origin master
```

3/ With gitk I see my 'master' branch has been merged twice: 2 graph loops with names 'master', 'origin/master', 'origin/proto' and 'origin/dev'.

Fine ! I got:

```
*   b5819e5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Version 0.3
* \   e85a4e8 (origin/development) Version 0.2
* \ \   415bcef Version 0.1
* | | 9539fb1 (origin/proto) Update
```

4/ but my problem is when cloning the project again (in a temp directory), with gitk, I no longer see the 'dev' name: It's look like the 'dev' branch is now part of the same 'master'. I only see two graph loops with 'master' and 'origin/master' and 'origin/proto'. It seems like 'dev' branch was removed.

```
*   b5819e5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Version 0.3
* \   e85a4e8 Version 0.2
* \ \   415bcef Version 0.1
* | | 9539fb1 (origin/proto) Update
```

What is the good manner to do for merging: local or remote ? I do not want to loose the branch name information 'dev' ! I think it's not possible to merge a special SHA1 from a remote branch, right ?

Note: with gitk I can make a reset --hard to a given SHA1 from a local branch but I cannot do it from a remote branch. If I could to do it, I think, the merge would not have lost my branch name.

**Edit: Partially self-answer**
It's because I did:

```
git merge --no-ff <sha1-from-dev-branch>
```

The SHA1 does not match the one from HEAD. If I take the last commit, the 'origin/dev' is finally displayed even in a cloned repo.

Comment: Git commits (and a merge is just a special case of a commit) don't know anything about branch names.  If you don't put the branch name in the commit message, then it's gone.

Comment: Seemed to me than when merging, git add the branch name information before the graph 'join' displayed as a horizontal arrow in gitk (and this is this information I'm loosing after a commit + clone while correctly displayed in my current working directory)

Comment: gitk adds labels based on whatever names you have in your repository. Add new names (new branch or tag names) and new labels appear; delete names, and labels vanish. Each repository's names are independent of any other repository's names, with some exceptions about names that are by convention *copied* (during cloning or other fetch operations; but that does not include local branch names, except for the initial creation of `master` or whatever name `git clone` creates via checkout).

Comment: @torek thanks, if I understand you well, on my working directory, after merging, etc, .. git created labels that gitk can understand and display but these informations are lost when committing. I just made tests: on my working directory gitk seems acting like a 'gitk --all' but filtering to see only impacted branches. After cloning, I find my label names back with gitk --all. Strange for me but I accept this behavior

Comment: It's not so much that they are *lost* when *committing*. Instead, they're not *added*. They exist now in your repository because they already existed in your repository. Make a new clone and you get one (1) branch, along with N remote-tracking names `origin/*` that match the branches on the repository from which you cloned. Create 2 or 3 new branch names in the local repository, and now you have 3 (2 new + 1 old) or 4 (3 new + 1 old) names that `gitk` will show. Merging doesn't *create* any new names.

Comment: @torek I was talking about remotes branches. Calling 'git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph' on my working directory show me:
*   b5819e5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Version 0.3
* \   e85a4e8 (origin/development) Version 0.2
* \ \   415bcef Version 0.1
* | | 9539fb1 (origin/proto) Update
while in the cloned project the "(origin/development)" is not shown and I supposed considered as part of master.

Comment: Is there an `origin/development` (in the clone where gitk does not show it)? How exactly did you make this clone?

Comment: @torek Yes ! And I finally understand: it's because I merged with a SHA1 that is not the one of HEAD so 'master' and 'dev' are joined as 'master' label and the label 'dev' is not shown. Once I merged the HEAD the label 'origin/dev' appears even on the cloned repo. I can close this topic. Thanks for your patience